# Copy record from and set limit as per another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert same record with two different values. I am having two separete tables `Table-x` and `Table-Y`.

`Table-x` contains zip codes which will multiple and `Table-y` contains rest of the columns.

`INSERT into Table-x (id,field1,field2,zip,field3) VALUES (NULL,val1,val2,<Tabley.zipcode>,val3)`

I want to execute above statement untill `Table-x` has zip codes

Comment: is there any relationship between tableX and tableY?

Comment: No my friend.
no any relationship i want to copy zip code from table-x and use in table-y

Comment: Can you please specify (maybe with an example) which table contains what  columns and based on that specify what you want to select and insert where?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WHERE .... IS NOT NULL`:

```
INSERT into Table-x (id,field1,field2,zip,field3) 
SELECT id, field1, field2, zip, field3 FROM Tabley
WHERE Tabley.zipcode IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT INTO...SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO TableX (id, field1, field2, zip, field3) 
SELECT NULL, @val1, @val2, zipcode, @val3
FROM TableY
```